# Why am I getting SIGABRT in this code?

Tags: c++, sigabrt

I checked my solution in my IDE.
But when I'm going to submit my solution, it throws an error `SIGABRT`.

Where is the problem?

It runs well on sample test cases in my IDE with this input:

```
1
5 6
5000 10000 3000 20 100
10000 2
800 2
600 1
10 8
1000 9
2000 10
111111
100000
000000
000001
100100
```

Constraints:

> 1 ≤ T ≤ 10, 1 ≤ NoOfCandidates, noOfCompanies ≤ 10^3, 0 ≤
>   minSalary[i] ≤ 10^9,   0 ≤ qual[i][j] ≤ 1 , 1 ≤ offeredSalary[i] ≤
>   10^9 , 1 ≤ maxJobOffers[i] ≤ 10^6,All elements of the array
>   offeredSalary are distinct

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<utility>
#define ll long long int

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int t;  cin>>t;
   while(t--)
   {
      int no_cand,no_comp;
      cin>>no_cand>>no_comp;
      vector<ll> minSalary(no_cand+1);
      for(int i=1;i<=no_cand;++i)
         cin>>minSalary[i];
      vector<ll> offeredSalary(no_comp+1);
      vector<ll> maxJobOffers(no_comp+1);
      vector<ll> hiring(no_comp+1);


      for(int i=1;i<=no_comp;++i)
      {
         cin>>offeredSalary[i]>>maxJobOffers[i];
         hiring[i]=maxJobOffers[i];
      }
      string str[no_cand+1];
      vector<int> qual[no_cand+1];
      cin.ignore();
      for(int i=1;i<=no_cand+1;++i)
      {
         getline(cin,str[i],'\n');
         for(int j=0;j<str[i].length();++j)
         {
            if(str[i][j]=='1' && minSalary[i]<=offeredSalary[j+1])
               qual[i].push_back(j+1);
         }
      }
      int placed=0,un_hired=0;
      ll amount =0;
      for(int i=1;i<=no_cand;++i)
      {
         vector< pair<ll,int> > offerLetter;
         for(int j=0;j<qual[i].size();++j)
         {
            int p=qual[i][j];
            if(maxJobOffers[p]>0)
            offerLetter.push_back(make_pair(offeredSalary[p],p));
         }
         if(offerLetter.size()==0)  continue;
         sort(offerLetter.begin(),offerLetter.end(),greater< pair<ll,int> >());
         pair<ll,int> temp=*offerLetter.begin();
         amount+=temp.first;
         --maxJobOffers[temp.second];
         ++placed;
         offerLetter.clear();
      }
      vector<ll>::iterator it1=maxJobOffers.begin()+1;
      vector<ll>::iterator it2=hiring.begin()+1;
      for( ;it1!=maxJobOffers.end() && it2!=hiring.end();++it1,++it2)
      {
        // cout<<*it1<<" "<<*it2<<endl;
         if(*it1==*it2)
         ++un_hired;
      }
      maxJobOffers.clear();
      hiring.clear();
      offeredSalary.clear();
      qual[no_cand+1].clear();
      cout<<placed<<" "<<amount<<" "<<un_hired<<"\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you have problems with indices and bounds. The first index of a `std::vector` is 0, the last in n - 1 if the `std::vector` has n elements. So the for-loop with `i <= no_card+1` access an element of `str` out of bounds. HTH

Comment: You should add the `c++` tag.

Comment: VLAs are at-best a language vendor extension and should not be used in modern C++. `string str[no_cand+1];` is a recipe for disaster, using (a) a VLA, and (b) a non-POD-type at that. And before you say, "but it works", so does driving a nail with a screwdriver if you try hard enough, but that doesn't make it *right*. Finally, stop trying to circumvent using 0-based indexing and *embrace* it. It will make the rest of your C or C++ career *much* easier.

Comment: If you're going to post "online judge" questions, be considerate and put the data in the program.  In other words, hard-code the data into the variables you have.  No one is going to want to waste their time typing in data every time they attempt to run your program.  When posting, structure your code so that we can simply take the code, copy it to our compiler, and without any changes, run the program *without having to type in the data every time*.  (I wish SO had this as a policy when posting these sorts of questions).